# Delphi 2010 to XE5. How to upgrade reports?

Tags: delphi, reporting, delphi-xe5

I currently use Delphi 2010.  Contemplating upgrading to current release, XE5.  My biggest concern is that I have applications that use RAVE Reports,and these reports would have to be migrated/upgraded.  My understanding is that the reporting tool switched from Rave to FastReports.  Is this accurate?  How do I migrate from Rave to FastReports?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fast Reports have produced a converter which will convert Rav files to FR3 files. See the blog entry at  http://www.fast -report.com/en/blog/26/show/ for more information

Comment: I intentionally broke the url (space after the first hyphen) as it won't let me post the proper URL in the answer for some reason!

Comment: Their domain was blacklisted for spam reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The light version of Rave Reports doesn't ship with Delphi any more, but the commercial edition is still [available from Nevrona](http://www.nevrona.com/order/index.html).  No new functionality, but it supports XE5.